# How to load control template in a resource dictionary in code for a calendar control

Tags: wpf, templates, calendar

I have a WPF calendar control and the template for the day has a property called

```
cal.DayTemplate =
```

I have created a dictionary file contaning my control template for the day of the calendar

But I am not sure how to load it into the `DayTemplate` property.

I have added my dictionary to the `Application.Resources` in `App.xaml`

the `x:Key` to my control template is `x:Key="DayTemplate"`

So I though to load it this would work

```
cal.DayTemplate = new DataTemplate("DayTemplate");
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Oops. Been a while since I had to do this.

I believe you want:

```
cal.DayTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.FindResource("DayTemplate");
```

See if that works.